# Is it possible to ignore a wrapper class during JAXB marshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to get JAXB to ignore a wrapper class during the Mashalling process, it makes sense to have this wrapper class in code, as it keep all related information together, however I need to get rid of it during the marshaling process. The following is the relevant code.

```
@XmlType(name = "root")
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElementRef
    private List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addResource(Resource resource) {
        resources.add(resource);
    }
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "", namespace = "")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Resource {

    @XmlElementRef
    private Element element;
    @XmlElementRef
    private FieldType fieldType;
    @XmlElementRef
    private ListType listType;
}
```

Root is the main object, and Resource is the wrapper object that I'd like not have a node created for. I still want the Element, FieldType and ListType within the Resource to be rendered however.

This is what I currently have:

```
<root>
    <>
        <element name="resource1"/>
        <fieldType name="resource1--type">
        </fieldType>
        <listType name="resource--list">
        </listType>
    </>
    <>
        <element name="resource2"/>
        <fieldType name="resource2--type">
        </fieldType>
        <listType name="resource2--list">
        </listType>
    </>
</root>
```

What I'd like to achieve is the following:

```
<root>
    <element name="resource1"/>
    <fieldType name="resource1--type">
    </fieldType>
    <listType name="resource--list">
    </listType>
    <element name="resource2"/>
    <fieldType name="resource2--type">
    </fieldType>
    <listType name="resource2--list">
    </listType>
</root>
```

I don't know if it's possible, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot achieve that in JAXB. Even if you would be able to serialize like this, using a XmlAdapter for example, it will be impossible to deserialize it.

Try this:

```
@XmlType(name = "root")
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Root {

    private ArrayList<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();

    public void addResource(Resource resource) {
        resources.add(resource);
    }

    @XmlElementRefs(value = { @XmlElementRef(type = Element.class),
                              @XmlElementRef(type = ListType.class),
                              @XmlElementRef(type = FieldType.class) })
    public List<Object> getResourceFields() {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (Resource r : resources) {
            list.add(r.getElement());
            list.add(r.getFieldType());
            list.add(r.getListType());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Basically `getRerourceFields` concatenates all the resources' fields in the same list.
If you cannot change the `Root` class, this could be your `RootAdapter` and use it as @Biju suggested.

Comment: Hi tibtof. Happily all I need to do serialize it, I don't have to worry about deserializing it. So if you think it's in any way possible that would be brilliant.

Comment: Tibtof, you're a scholar mate! That sorted me out, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You probably will have to create an XmlAdapter for your Root class, this adapter should basically map your root instances to a different type, where you can flatten your root structure before marshalling - along these lines:

```
public class CustomRootAdapter extends
                    XmlAdapter<CustomRoot,Root>> {
@Override
public Root unmarshal(CustomRoot v) throws Exception {
    return null;//if you are not keen on unmarshalling..
}
@Override
public CustomRoot marshal(Root v) throws Exception {
    return ...;
}
```

}

You can register this Custom adapter using:

`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomRootAdapter.class)` with your `Root` class

Comment: -1 because XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation can't be used with XmlRootElement annotation. See [javadocs](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html)

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like exactly what `@XMLTransient` does.

> When placed on a class, it indicates that the class shouldn't be mapped to XML by itself. Properties on such class will be mapped to XML along with its derived classes, as if the class is inlined.

See [javadoc](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.3/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the response. I did try that, but it kept on giving me the following error: Invalid XmlElementRef : Type "class ...classes.root.Resource" or any of its subclasses are not known to this context. This occurs when I only have XmlTransient on the Resource class. Not too sure what's happening there.

Comment: Did you put @XMLTransient on the private field you want to ignore? Were there any other JAXB annotations on that field? Did you leave all the other JAX annotations on the Resource class as in the example above?

Comment: I put XmlTransient initially on the private list in the Root class. Instead of XmlElementRef. This didn't throw an exception, but didn't display any of the classes contained within the Resource class. I then put in on the Resource class itself, but this threw the above exception. I've tried several combinations, leaving the JAX annotations in, removing them. Each time I got an exception.