# change inheritance to composition for existing jaxb class structure keeping the current xml structure unchanged

Tags: java, inheritance, marshalling, composition, jaxb2

In my code base I have `B extdnds A` but I want to make it: `B uses A`. This is my try:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class A {

    @XmlElement(name ="aString")
    private String aString;
```

B class contains A (composition):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class B {

    @XmlElement
    private A a = new A(); // has A

    @XmlElement
    private String bString;
```

There is Root that contains list of B

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ABs {

    @XmlElement(name = "b-list")
    private final List<B> bList = Constraints.constrainedList(new ArrayList<B>(), Constraints.notNull());


    public void add(B...bb) {
        for(B b : bb) {
            bList.add(b);
        }
    }
}
```

My test, marshals Bs to Systetem.out

```
 ABs abs = new ABs();
        abs.add( new B("bStringValue", "aStringValue"));

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ABs.class);

        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        m.marshal(abs, System.out);
```

Result:

```
<aBs>
    <b-list>
        <a>
            <aString>aStringValue</aString>
        </a>
        <bString>bStringValue</bString>
    </b-list>
</aBs>
```

But I want result like this: as if I use **inheritance**. Like as if `B extends A` :

```
<aBs>
    <b-list>
        <aString>aStringValue</aString>
        <bString>bStringValue</bString>
    </b-list>
</aBs>
```

**How can I do this?**

**EDIT:**

The question is really about: **How to omit/ignore tag `<a>` for A class when use it in B class. I.e. to not marshal to `<a>` but to all fields/tags that inside `<a>`**

Like:

```
@XmlElement(name = "") // empty
private A a = new A();
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

[Is it possible to ignore a wrapper class during JAXB marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930396/is-it-possible-to-ignore-a-wrapper-class-during-jaxb-marshalling)

The answer is: **impossible**.

Actually my question is kind of duplication of that one. But my question is related to ***architectural side of issue***.

It seems that JAXB is not the best thing to use If you want to stay with `XML` structure like it was before (imagine that `XML` is `REST API` you not suppose to change, but still you wish to change classes around it) but change the way the classes connect to each other.

It(`jaxb`) **breaks a freedom**. The classes become a bit (too much I mean) **anemic**..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class B {

@XmlElement
private String aString;// you don't need to create the class A (aString  is like bString lement)

@XmlElement
private String bString;
```

Comment: but A and B are already created, and I don not want to repeat myself putting all fields from A to B. And I can not delete those classes to make one (they both have lost of fields in reality: not juts a,b). Now what I have is: B extends A, but I want" B uses A